# getting stackoverflow exception while passing value in different thread in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, stack-overflow

I am creating an opc server with third party dll.they had given an example in which all functions r running on a different thread.
here is the example,OPCServer.cs:

```
public static OpcServer CreateInstanceAsync()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(InitializationThread));
        OpcServer opcServer = new OpcServer();
        thread.Start(opcServer);
        thread.Join();
        return opcServer;
    }
 static void InitializationThread(object arg)
    {
        ((OpcServer)arg).Initialize();
    }

    void Initialize()
    {
         //some stuff
    }

  public void UpdateValues(string[] n)
    {
    this.BeginUpdate();
    value1 = (object[])n;
    for (int i = 0; i < tag_count; i++)
    {
       this.SetTag(tag_ids[i], value1[i], Quality.Good, FileTime.UtcNow);
    }
   this.EndUpdate(false);
    }
```

I am getting problem in the method UpdateValues();
in the main form:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        opcServer = OpcServer.CreateInstanceAsync();
        opcServer.UpdateValues(valuesInArray);
    }
```

there is a timer & the UpdateValues() method will call at every time tick with a new value. interval is 10 secs.

```
     private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        opcServer.UpdateValues(valuesInArray);
    }
```

the program is running smoothly for some time. but after that it showing stack overflow exception.,sometimes pc got hanged.i don't understand why? how do i get rid from this? the OPCServer.cs is given by the 3rd party.my work is to passing value in that particular method.will i have to create a new thread each time i will call that method?

Comment: 1.) What's an OPC server?
2.) What does this.BeginUpdate()?
3.) What does this.SetTag(..)?
4.) What does this.EndUpdate(false)?

Comment: An OPC Server is a software application that acts as a protocol converter.it creates tags & all these methods are given by the 3rd party dll to update tags.SetTag() takes 4 arguments.My work is to continue pass data to updateTags().it works fine upto some time,then showing error.

Comment: Could you set breakpoint on "return opcServer;" line in CreateInstanceAsync method and check if it called?

Comment: @ mt_serg: I had given breakpoint on return,it is returning all the static members it has but not the method.

Comment: What I tried to understand here is why a thread is used for initializing opcServer. Looks like it doesn't make any sence because right after start we call Join and just wait (block the caller thread) until InitializationThread method completes. So, at first, why not just create instance like this: public static OpcServer CreateInstance() { var opcServer = new OpcServer(); opcServer.Initialize(); return opcServer;}

Comment: @mt_serg : it is required to use different thread to initialize because according to this dll it requires [MTAThread] to run all methods where as window application run in [STAThread].so,main methods run on [STA]as usual and all other methods are run in different thread and these code are provided by the 3rd party.

Comment: @mahua22 : you actually don't need this if you are happy to freeze your form while your server is initializing

Comment: @mahua22, In that case you are not allowed to call UpdateValues from ui thread in Form1 constructor and in time1_Tick event(if you use System.Windows.Forms.Timer its tick called in ui thread).
So, you can create a Thread for all method call, but better to use Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { opcServer.UpdateValues(valuesInArray); });  because Task uses thread pool and you will not have a thread creating overhead.

Comment: @mt_serg: I will have to do this application in framework 2.0 because of the dll and "Task" is not supported in this framework. what to do now?

Comment: @mahua22, in .net 2.0 you can use BackroundWorker class. Check documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @mt_serg: I had seen the document but not understand properly.can you give some hint how do i do this?

Comment: @mahua22, It's simple, add this http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?gf4seewr8k0g to your class and call UpdateValuesInANewThread() inside constructor and tick event.

Comment: @mt_serg: I had done as you told but still an error occurs "attempt to read/write protected memory,this is often an indication of other memory is corrupted". please help me.....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38166/discussion-between-mt-serg-and-mahua22)

Answer (score 0):

Try BackgroundWorker for updating form while running long process. Use ProgressChanged event to update the form values else invoke a delegate to update form controls.

Comment: I don't have to update the form. I have to pass the value from a variable in the form to the method which is suppose to run in different thread in a timer interval.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)  and then use events and delegates to interact with form elements.

Using the Task Parallel Library is very easy:

```
foreach (DriveInfo info in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
    if (info.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
        {
             var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => scanFiles(findType, info.RootDirectory.Name));                        
        }
}
```

This would be an example of interacting with the form elements:

In my external class:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Delegate for setting text box text
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        public delegate void TextBoxEventHandler(object sender, TextEventArgs e);
        /// <summary>
        /// Event for changing tool bar text
        /// </summary>
        public event TextBoxEventHandler ChangeTextBoxText = delegate { };
        /// <summary>
        /// Function that raises set tool bar text event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="s"></param>
        public void SetTextBoxText(string s)
        {
            ChangeTextBoxText(this, new TextEventArgs(s));
        }
```

In my form:

```
    scanner.ChangeTextBoxText += scanner_ChangeTextBoxText;

    private void scanner_ChangeTextBoxText(object sender, FS.TextEventArgs e)
    {
        addMessage(e.Message);
    }

    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    private void addMessage(string message)
    {
        if (edtContents.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(addMessage);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { message });
        }
        else
        {
            edtContents.Text += String.Format("{0}{1}", message, Environment.NewLine);
            edtContents.SelectionStart = edtContents.Text.Length;
            edtContents.ScrollToCaret();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all why do you create a thread here

```
public static OpcServer CreateInstanceAsync()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(InitializationThread));
    OpcServer opcServer = new OpcServer();
    thread.Start(opcServer);
    thread.Join();
    return opcServer;
}
```

because probably i think, you just don't want to hang your main form creation once you got the OpcServer object, you are just using the same instance to call the UpdateValues() in a timer.

now as you are piling things up in this call . how many updates you are adding.

```
this.SetTag(tag_ids[i], value1[i], Quality.Good, FileTime.UtcNow);
```

There must be some method to remove tags which are Old/Obsolete.

Check for the API documentation for freeing up the objects